# Unable to copy file Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2013

After installing [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (Spatial)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/)  package,I get build errors

- Error    14  Could not copy     "myapp\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.1\nativeBinaries\x86\msvcr100.dll" to "bin\SqlServerTypes\x86\msvcr100.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
- Error    26  Could not copy "myapp\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.1\nativeBinaries\x86\SqlServerSpatial110.dll" to "bin\SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial110.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
- Error    15  Unable to copy file "myapp\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.1\nativeBinaries\x86\msvcr100.dll" to "bin\SqlServerTypes\x86\msvcr100.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\SqlServerTypes\x86\msvcr100.dll' because it is being used by another process.
- Error    27  Unable to copy file "myapp\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.1\nativeBinaries\x86\SqlServerSpatial110.dll" to "bin\SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial110.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial110.dll' because it is being used by another process.

After Investigation I've found that my iis worker process block these files.After restart iis,application building successfuly,but than erros appears.

How can I solve this problem???

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope,I cannot find solution

Comment: Right now if I close VS and reopen it and Clean the Solution, it builds just fine... but at this rate I am going to finish debugging next year...

Comment: Before build I stop iis(kill w3wp.exe process) or for iis express kill iisexpress.exe process.It work but not good solution

Comment: Any idea how to stop this issue from happening on an Azure web app?

Answer (score 8):

I found a natural solution for this.

I just stop IIS before the compilation begin and then start again IIS after the compilation.

In your project go to Properties > Build Events:

- Pre-build event command line: iisreset /STOP
- Post-build event command line: iisreset /START

Answer (score 3):

It looks like when you uninstall the NuGet package, references in the csproj are not deleted. Also, I found some references to those dlls in a file related to Git called ms-persist.xml - but this probably wasn't the problem. So after deleting all of that, the build worked.

Answer (score 2):

So I encountered the same issue and found a very simple fix.

First remove the reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types or uninstall the nuget package. Re-install the package and presto.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue and just came across a decent solution. In my case, I had two projects that were being started and run inside of IIS Express every time I started to debug in VS 2013, even though I had selected only one startup project inside of the solution explorer. I noticed that every time I stopped debugging, only one of my apps inside of IIS Express would terminate, while the other would continue running. A subsequent clean/build would show the error you're encountering for the app that did not terminate. Turns out you can select multiple startup projects in VS, which will tell IIS Express to start both of them when starting to debug (which was oddly already happening in my case, even though I only had one startup project selected) and will also tell IIS Express to terminate both applications when Stopping Debugging. When all applications inside of IIS Express are terminated, I'm able to successfully clean/build without getting this error. Instructions on how to set multiple startup projects can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can recycle & restart your application pool that locked the mentioned files as a part of your deployment process. Recycling application pool unlocks the files and you are able to overwrite them.

For local deployment you can specify a pre-build event (`DefaultAppPool` is the name of your application pool):

```
c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool "DefaultAppPool"
```

For automated deployment (eg. from your build server) you can tell `msdeploy` to restart application pool as a part of deployment process:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:recycleApp="Default Web Site/myapp" -dest:auto
```

For more info, see Web Deploy recycleApp provider [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522997(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue last few months and I have to stop the IIS server and then compile my code and then started the server every time. So it would very weird on development time.

I have found out the solution, please check the below point:
 1. Just change the "Copy To Output Directory" property value is "Copy if newer" of "SqlServerSpatial140.dll" file.

when you have changed it you have to restart the application only one time.